# Exception raised when using like on grails prepared statement

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, prepared-statement

Since I cannot achieve the needed query using Hibernate createCriteria, I am stuck on using the common Mysql join. But a part of my query is failing for some reason when I am using the parameterized query.
The code that return datasource connection is

```
def getSqlInstance(){            
def conn = dataSource.connection
Sql sql = new Sql(conn)
return sql;
}
```

when I use the query of *some variation of* following form

```
def conn = getSqlInstance(); 
def result = conn.rows("select distinct u.user_id from user_role u inner join (select id from role where authority like %:roles% )r on u.role_id = r.id",params)
```

I get the following exception

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%')r on u.role_id = r.id' at line 1. Stacktrace follows:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%')r on u.role_id = r.id' at line 1**

can someone help out with this please

Comment: This query executes as expected If I use "=" instead or "like"

Comment: I am able to rectify this error using `'%':roles'%'` but the query still throws error on use of characters like **<' & "**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is SQL-based

```
def result = conn.rows("select distinct u.user_id from user_role u inner join 
                        (select id from role where authority like 
                         concat('%',:roles,'%') ) r on u.role_id = r.id",
                       params)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what i was doing wrong, i had to represent the `%` as a part of the map to be passed itself. I got the desired result using

```
`def result = conn.rows("select distinct u.user_id from user_role u inner join (select id from role where authority like ? )r on u.role_id = r.id","%"+role+"%")`
```